# Preventing users to enter negative sign '-' in angular input field

Tags: javascript, html, angular

is there a way to stop users from entering `-` sign in angular inputs?

Or clear the sign as soon as they entered it?
I don't want values like `-1, 9-, 124-5433`.

Comment: Do you only want to accept numeric values. is that it?

Comment: You can register a `(ngModelChange)` [event binding](https://angular.io/guide/event-binding) and remove the sign. An element can have multiple event bindings of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to accept numeric vaues you can add a `min` attribute to the html input, like

```
<input type="number" min="0">
```

So this won't let you insert negative values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below way in your input field using `oninput` I hope it work for you

```
<input oninput="return event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')" type="text">
```